# Max length TSQLConnection.Params values

Tags: delphi, interbase, dbexpress

Hello fellow StackOverflowers,

Currently I'm facing a situation where it seems that there is a maximum length for the Database property of a `TSQLConnection` object in Delphi.

When I open the connection to my database I get the following error when I use a rather long (154 chars) database name:

`dbExpress Error: [0x0015]: Connection failed
SQL Server Error: unrecognized database parameter block
wrong version of database parameter block`

When I relocate my database file to another location (and with that reduce the length of the path) it will connect to the database.

I am currently using the Object Inspector to set the connection properties of the `TSQLConnection` object.

Basically, my question comes down to this:

Does a `TSQLConnection` have a maximum length for the values set in the `Params` property? And if so, what is the maximum length of these values?

Comment: `TSQLConnections.Params` is `TStrings` so if here is a limit this is limit of TStrings.  http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/30333

Comment: You've tagged your question "Interbase".  Are you actually asking about an Interbase server, or some other back-end server?

Comment: @MartynA I am working with an interbase server.

Comment: Ah, ok, I was puzzled by the "SQL Server Error" in the error message.

Comment: @MartynA I agree that the error message I'm getting is somewhat vague and not really explaining.

Comment: Please could you add to your q: a) Delphi version b) Interbase version c) the DFM contents for your TSqlConnection d) the exact code you use open the connection and any of the Params values you add or modify in code.  Reason I ask is that working on my answer, I've run into some erratic behviour, apparently of the IB server, and would like to compare what you're doing with what I am.

Comment: @MartynA I am using Delphi 7 and Interbase XE. Currently, as described in the post, I set the parameters of the connection in the object explorer. I also use the object explorer to set the `connected` property to `true`.

Comment: Tks.  The erratic behviour I mentioned turned out to be mine, rather than the s/ware(!).  Have you tried my answer in D7?  I can't myself at the moment as the machine I have IB for D7 set up on is in for repair at the moment.

Answer (score 4):

**Update**

I've found two ways to open a copy of Employee.Gdb in a folder with a 160-character name ('abcdefghij0123456789' x 8).

What I did firstly was to edit the DBXConnections.Ini file and changed the Database parameter in the [IBConnection] section to read

```
Database=localhost:D:\abcdefghij01234567890abcdefghij01234567890abcdefghij01234567890abcdefghij01234567890abcdefghij01234567890abcdefghij01234567890abcdefghij01234567890abcdefghij01234567890\employee.gdb
```

Then, I can successfully connect to it, open the Employee.Gdb and make changes to the Customer table.  I have verified the changes in IBConsole just in case the copy of Employee.Gdb wasn't the one I assumed it was.

Subsequently, I've found that I can create and open the db in code using Delphi Seattle and Interbase XE7, as follows:

```
function LongPath : String;
begin
  Result := 'D:\' + DupeString('abcdefghij0123456789', 8);
end;

function LongDBName : String;
begin
  Result := LongPath + '\Employee.Gdb';
end;

procedure TForm1.OpenDB;
var
  Ini : TMemIniFile;
const
  scDBXConIni = 'C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\dbExpress\17.0\dbxconnections.ini';
  scSourceDB = 'D:\Delphi\Databases\Interbase\Employee.Gdb';
begin
  Ini := TMemIniFile.Create(scDBXConIni);
  try
    // First, blank out the Database value in the IBConnection section
    //  of DBXConnections.Ini
    Ini.WriteString('IBConnection', 'Database', '');
    Ini.UpdateFile;

    //  Next, create the long-named directory and copy Employee.Gdb to it
    if not DirectoryExists(LongPath) then
      MkDir(LongPath);
     Assert(CopyFile(PChar(scSourceDB), PChar(LongDBName), False));

     //  Set LoadParamsOnConnect to False so that the SqlConnection uses
     //  the value of the Database we are about to give it
     SqlConnection1.LoadParamsOnConnect := False;
     SqlConnection1.Params.Values['Database'] := LongDBName;
     SqlConnection1.Connected := True;

     //  Open the CDS to view the data
     CDS1.Open;

  finally
    Ini.Free;
  end;

end;
```

The critical step in doing it this way is setting `LoadParamsOnConnect` to `False`, which I confess I'd overlooked in earlier attempts to get this code to work.

I've got some earlier versions of Delphi on this machine, so if you're not using Seattle and the above code doesn't work for you, tell me which one you *are* using and I'll see if I can try that.

**<s>[Original answer]</s>

Actually, I think that this may be an error occurring in one of the DBX DLLs.

I created a folder with a 160-character name, then copied the demo Employee.Gdb database into it.  Interbase XE7's IBConsole can open the db without error.  So could a small test project contructed with IBX components in Delphi Seattle.

However, with an equivalent DBX project, when I use the code below

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SqlConnection1.Params.Values['database'] := 'D:\abcdefghij01234567890abcdefghij01234567890abcdefghij01234567890abcdefghij01234567890abcdefghij01234567890abcdefghij01234567890abcdefghij01234567890abcdefghij01234567890\employee.gdb';
  SqlConnection1.Connected := True;
end;
```

I get an error in

```
procedure TDBXDynalinkConnection.DerivedOpen;
var
  Count:          TInt32;
  Names:          TWideStringArray;
  Values:         TWideStringArray;
  IsolationLevel: Longint;
  DBXError:       TDBXErrorCode;
begin
  Count := FConnectionProperties.Properties.Count;
  FConnectionProperties.GetLists(Names, Values);

  CheckResult(FMethodTable.FDBXConnection_Connect(FConnectionHandle, Count, Names, Values));
  DBXError := FMethodTable.FDBXConnection_GetIsolation(FConnectionHandle, IsolationLevel);
```

'I/O error for file "database.gdb" 
Error while trying to open file
The operation completed successfully'

and the Database param of the SqlConnection is left at the value 'Database.Gdb', which is **not** the value I specified, of course, nor was it the value specified in the params in the IDE, which was 'd:\delphi\databases\interbase\employee.gdb'.

I wondered if I could work around this problem by SUBSTing a drive to the 'abcdefg ...' path.  I tried that and opening the database as "x:\employee.gdb" , but I get the same error in my DBX app, and also IBConsole cannot access the db either.

I think you need a shorter physical path!**

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Though it seems like you are running into a slightly different issue as I am. Currently my path is not exceeding 160 characters.

Nevertheless, I really appreciate your effort :)

Answer (score 1):

This is related to MSSql Server:

> As a general guideline, long path names greater than 160 characters
>   might cause problems.

from Microsoft TechNet - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165768(v=sql.105).aspx